# A cryptic list of words

Tags: word, cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, password

You find yourself trapped in a dark room. You say, "hello" and bright lights turn on, flooding the area. You see a piece of paper on the ground:

`VIG: e(d(innby, eauuu), innby)`

You also see a keyboard on the ground with wires heading towards the only door in the room. With no luck, you try to push the door open. It seems you must determine the password, type it into the keyboard, and escape!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The password is:

> magic

Process:

> Use Vigenere Cipher and follow the order of operations:
>  Decrypt innby with key eauuu to get enthe.
>  Encrypt enthe with key innby to get magic.